# Https connection issue

Tags: delphi, remobjects

this is my first attempt here so please don't be harsh

I'm hosting a home server and i need it to run on https

I've achieved that with the apache server from XAMPP and it works fine, meaning i am connecting to it and i see my sources both from localhost and from exterior(i have a free domain)

Now the problem is that i have another server developed with delphi and remobjects. When i tested this server at work it worked perfectly, just like the previous one i could connect and view my sources. When i moved it home and tried to access it i get ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED. At work i ran the server on windows 7  64-bit full updates and eset nod 32. At home i ran it on windows 8.1 64-bit full updates and avast free. I already checked my firewall and the port isn't blocked since i tested it with the apache server and that one works. I also checked the antivirus internet firewall and not a problem here either.

If anyone could point out what i might missed and why i get this error i'll really appreciate it.

Comment: Why is this HTTPS specific, does it mean it works well with HTTP?

Comment: did you launched tit stand-alone or from IDE debug session ?

Comment: yes it works very well on http...but i need to run the server on https for dropbox redirect. And yes i also launched the server in debug mode but i was unable to find the issue. As un update i tested the server on multiple machines(like 5 pc's) and it seems it's only giving this error on windows 8 - 8.1. I got some information it might be about an windows security update but noone pinpointed wich one, fior the moment i'm runing it on http and testing it on localhost